# Remainder of $\frac{x^{60}+x^{48}+x^{36}+x^{24}+x^{12}+1}{x^{5}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the remainder of the polynomial division $$\frac{x^{60}+x^{48}+x^{36}+x^{24}+x^{12}+1}{x^{5}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1}$$

I know that the answer is 6, but I am not getting that when I tried to solve as follows:

I first recognized both numerator and denominator as geometric series, so thus this division is equal to:

$$\frac{\frac{1\left( 1-x^{72} \right)}{\left( 1-x^{12} \right)}}{\frac{1\left( 1-x^{6} \right)}{1-x}}$$

This is equal to $$\frac{(1-x) \left(1-x^{72}\right)}{\left(1-x^6\right) \left(1-x^{12}\right)}$$

However, the remainder of this division is not $6$, but is rather $$6 - 6 x - 6 x^{12} + 6 x^{13}$$

Why do I not get the right answer?

Comment: Try reducing that remainder modulo $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Note that modulo $1+x+\cdots +x^5$, you just have $x^6\equiv 1$.

Comment: @Ragnar How did you get that $x^6 \equiv 1$?

Comment: @user2612743 $(1+x+\cdots+x^5)(x-1)=x^6-1$, so $x^6-1=0$, so $x^6=1$.

Comment: @Ragnar -- ok, got it. That was similar to my original approach of converting both numerator and denominator to geometric sums and simplifying (as you can see in the above post). Why did that approach yield an incorrect answer?

Comment: I **think** the problem is that in the end you are not working modulo $1+\cdots +x^5$ anymore but modulo $(1-x^6)(1-x^{12})$. The $1-x^{12}$ should be in the numerator of the fraction and then you should try modulo $1-x^6$, but then you are still not looking modulo $1+\cdots +x^5$, so it should be the remainder of $$\frac{\frac{1-x^{72}}{(1-x)(1-x^{12})}}{1+x+\cdots+x^5}$$where the upper fraction is evaluated first (which is possible because it evaluates to a polynomial)

Comment: @Ragnar No, that results in a remainder of $-\frac{6}{x-1}$. Also, shouldn't the remainder stay the same regardless of how the quotient is manipulated? Because shouldn't $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=A(x) + R(x)$ regardless of how $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is expressed?

Comment: No, that is not true, because for example the remainder of (iteger division) $\frac 32$ is $1$ but the remainder of $\frac 64$ is $2$, so the remainder gets multiplied by the common factor by which you multiply numerator and denominator.

Comment: @user: I've edited my answer to explain your questions about what went wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nishant said, work modulo the denominator. Then, because $$x^6-1=(x-1)(x^5+\cdots+1)$$ you have $x^6$ is equivalent to 1.

But then $x^{60}=(x^6)^{10}$ is equivalent to... what? And what happens with the other powers in the numerator of your original fraction?

EDIT

Here's an explanation of what's going on with your approach. Note that if $cd\neq0$, then $$a\equiv r\bmod{b}\leftrightarrow acd\equiv rcd\bmod{bcd}$$

So if you turn your attention from the division of $a/b$ by rewriting $a=ac/c$ and $b=bd/d$ and getting the new division of $acd/bcd$, your remainder will be off by a factor of $cd$.

In your problem, $$c=1-x^{12}$$ and $$d=1-x$$ so you must divide the remainder you got by $$cd=(1-x^{12})(1-x)=x^{13}-x^{12}-x+1$$

which does indeed yield 6.

Comment: Why doesn't converting to a geometric series work though (as I did)?

Comment: I didn't work out whether the remainder you claimed there is correct, but I suspect you made an error.

Comment: I used wolfram-alpha to check and the remainder is right but it does not match the correct answer of $6$.

Comment: @user2612743: Just read the comments of Nishant and Ragnar. They explain everything.

Comment: @TonyK That doesn't explain why the geometric series approach fails though. Reducing $6-6x-6x^{12}+6x^{13}$ mod the denominator gives $0$.

Comment: Also, how did you arrive at the fact that $x^6 \equiv 1$?

Comment: @user: from the geometric series formula: $x^6-1=(x-1)(x^5+\cdots+1)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Ok. I see how to arrive at the answer now. But I am still wondering why my original approach of converting both numerator and denominator to geometric sums and simplifying did not work...

Comment: @user2612743: It did work! You just stopped too soon.

Comment: @TonyK Even if I continue and again reduce modulo $x^5 + ... + 1$ I get $0$, not $6$.

Comment: @user2612743: Oh, you're right! I'm sorry.

Comment: @user: I've added an explanation to my answer.